# How can I make my own graphic interface?

Tags: c#, java, c, graphics, portable-applications

I'v just learned a few languages (for 2 years now), and now I want to make programs with graphic interfaces. Thing is, I just don't know which languages to use.

What languages/programs (and what methods of these programs) are used to make programs with graphic interface? (I know that C# and JAVA are graphic, but I don't know what methods...)

What languages/programs (and what methods of these programs) are used to make applications to IPhone, Android ,and whatever ?

languages/programs (and what methods of these programs) are used to make/edit videos?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: All of the above menitioned languages are used for all of the tasks you've mentioned... your question is way too broad for SO.

Comment: In my point of view, Java is mainly for corporate applications. C is commonly used for game development.

Comment: C has very good built-in graphic libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all programming languages have libraries that help you create a GUI (Graphical User Interface). Most programming languages, including C++, C#, and Java are general-purpose programming languages - you can use them to program whatever you want.

For Java for example, see this tutorial: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

If you want to write an [Android app](http://developer.android.com/index.html), you'll program in Java.

For [iOS and Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/), you'll most likely write your app in Objective-C.

Comment: I know that all languages have libraries that help you create a GUI , but not all languages are FOR GUI (like C++?), so it might work on Windows, but not an other OS.  JAVA programming can work on all OS, because the program always require java installed on the PC, so the GUI programming is the same in all OS, no?

Comment: @7890 Why would you say C++ isn't for GUI programming?  I would think C++ would make a great language to do GUI programming in, if you can find the libraries to allow you to do it. There are number of cross platform C/C++ based libraries (Note I'm personally a Swing programmer ;))

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all higher level languages use graphic interface. you just have to do your research to find out how to use GUI in each language. Applications used on the iPhone are written in Objective-C and Android uses java for their apps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague. But I'll give you some advice. Before asking this kind of question on stackoverflow, you really should make a search on your own with google.

About graphic interface using JAVA, you can use [swing](https://www.google.lu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CEsQFjAB&url=http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing&ei=1qIAUrmUN4SMswbc3IGYDw&usg=AFQjCNEtbuJqikUwLj2JRyfcUkFgDrCI8wD) which is the most famous way to do it (especially if you're a beginner and want to familiarize with graphic interface development concepts). But there are a lot of other libraries to do GUI, for exemple if you want to do with 3D you have [openGL lib](http://opengl.j3d.org/) or [jMonkey](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) (uses openGl).

About [Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html), it has its own SDK in java.

About iOS (iPhone), it is made with ObjectiveC.

And about C#, I don't know a lot about it but if you do a quite search on google you can find things like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173080%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).